# From the functions that map the unit circle into itself, are those that fix a finite number of points a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If G is the group of the functions that map the unit circle (in the plain) into itself. I am having trouble to prove that the functions that fix a finite number of points of the circle and move the other ones form a subgroup, first of all, I can't understand what'll be the identity element, a function that fix every point in the circle has the same property of just fixing a finite number of them? Also, if I compose two of such functions, can it be the case that some points get overlapped? So the final result is not a unit circle? I've been searching for answers but haven't found a straight one, don't know what I'm missing. Any pointer will be very appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: The identity in a subgroup is always the identity in the entire group. Certainly the identity function fixes the finite amount of points fixed by these special functions. Also, i would guess that the larger group consists of all *bijective* functions from the circle to itself.  That guarantees inverses (necessary for it to be a group), and guarantees that composition of functions (which is the multiplication in the group) is also a bijection from the circle to itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, the bijection property is something that didn't came up in class or in my research! But makes perfect sense now :) Regards

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. I could read it in two ways: 1) There's some finite set of points $S$ such that every function $f$ in the group fixes everything in $S$: $(\forall x \in S) f(x) = x$. (But individual functions $f$ could have more fixed points.) Or: 2) For every function $f$ in the group, the set $\{x : f(x) = x\}$ is finite (but could be a different set for each function). I think the functions in (2) do not form a group (because the identity function is not included), but the functions in (1) do.

Comment: in your second point, (#2) what happens if the set is finite, but is always the same for all points? Why it doesn't contains the identity function? The function that fixes every point is not a function that fix the same set of points?